# How can we initialise datepicker into a textbox which is appended by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, yii, jquery-ui-datepicker

In yii framework of PHP I'm trying to append a textbox then initialise the datepicker.
I already have two static textbox with datepicker working fine in the from and two more needed to be added and datepicker be initialised in those textbox.

When I'm trying to initalise after ajax success call. It is showing

> datepicker is not a function

My ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (html) {
                $('.append_more_parents:last').append(html);
                var num_form = parseInt($('.count').length + 2);
                $('.count:last').text('Parental Responsibility ' + num_form);
                $form = $('#appended_form');
                $form.replaceWith($form.html());
                container_id++;
                $('#datepicker').datepicker();
            },
            error: function (err) {
                bootbox.alert('Sorry adding of parental details failed! Please try again');
            }
});
```

Comment: Have you included `datepicker` library?

Comment: I already have jquery.ui.js and jquery.js

Comment: is the `#datepicker` id on your html?

Answer (score 2):

If It is showing "datepicker is not a function" It seems that Jquery datepicker library is not included in your HTML page ?

Comment: can u please tell  me the datepicker jquery library. as we mostly use datepicker with inbulit widget of Yii.I already have jquery.ui.js and jquery.js.